# How to condition on a list of parameters in PGSQL

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking to input a list of integers into a function and return rows based on this. In this case, I want to select some attributes based on employer id, e.g. select where employer id = 102,103 and 105.

This is what I have tried.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy(VARIADIC e_id NUMERIC[])
RETURNS TABLE (
    emp_id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR,
    last_name VARCHAR,
    salary INT
)
AS $$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY SELECT em.emp_id, em.first_name, em.last_name, em.salary
    FROM employee em
    WHERE em.emp_id IN e_id;
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT *
FROM dummy(102, 103, 105);
```

The error appears to be from the line containing WHERE. How am I able to select based on the list of integers e_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `WHERE em.emp_id IN e_id`

Since you are dealing with a list of numbers, you could just use [the `any` construct](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN19712) instead of `in`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy(VARIADIC e_id NUMERIC[])
RETURNS TABLE (
    emp_id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR,
    last_name VARCHAR,
    salary INT
)
AS $$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY SELECT em.emp_id, em.first_name, em.last_name, em.salary
    FROM employee em
    WHERE em.emp_id = any (e_id);
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=2161cb348e423dff9ebefe4d7082b13d)**

create table employee(emp_id int, first_name varchar(50), last_name varchar(50), salary int);
    insert into employee values 
        (1, 'a', 'b', 50), 
        (2, 'c', 'd', 100), 
        (3, 'e', 'f', 400);

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy(VARIADIC e_id NUMERIC[])
RETURNS TABLE (
    emp_id INT,
    first_name VARCHAR,
    last_name VARCHAR,
    salary INT
)
AS $$
BEGIN 
    RETURN QUERY SELECT em.emp_id, em.first_name, em.last_name, em.salary
    FROM employee em
    WHERE em.emp_id = any (e_id);
END; $$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

SELECT * FROM dummy(1, 2);
```

```
emp_id | first_name | last_name | salary
-----: | :--------- | :-------- | -----:
     1 | a          | b         |     50
     2 | c          | d         |    100
```